# javascript string with white spaces how to get an array of strings from it that without whitecaps in it?

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
myStringtoSplit = "SomeText     123"
```

I want to get an array that has only 2 things in it:
[SomeText,123]

I am now using split():

```
var array = myStringtoSplit.split(" ");
```

doing so though gives me an array with length 6. So the array has at [0] = "SomeText"
between index 1 and 4 has white spaces and then at index 5 it has "123"

How can I make the resulting array only have the two strings in it with no white spaces?

```
So I want end up with this:
[SomeText,123]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: when I user trim() is says this: ReferenceError: trim is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: @Robert `trim` only removes whitespaces at the beginning and end. But not in the middle.

Comment: Err right, I had it in my head that it'd split it into something like `["   thing   "]`, forgot that it would create a bunch of `["","",""]` entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove whitespaces at the beginning and end.

And then you can use the regex `/\s+/`, which matches multiple whitespaces, as the separator for [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
"SomeText     123".trim().split(/\s+/)
```

Note `trim` was added in EcmaScript5, so you may need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility) it.

Comment: so, this works for that string, but if I change the string to "SomeText " I still get an array with length = 2 where at index 1 in the array I have a white space...

Comment: I am running this in simple .js file from terminal using "node myFile.js" and it tells me this when I use trim():   ReferenceError: trim is not defined     at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: @zumzum If the string may contain whitespaces at the beginning or end, you can `trim` before splitting. Note `trim` was added in ES5, so you may need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility) it.